# Why need to assign constructor back to my custom error type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I am learning "Error Handling in JavaScript" and read articles on site point. In the articles, it shows the way to make custom error type:

```
function DivisionByZeroError(message) {
  this.name = "DivisionByZeroError";
  this.message = (message || "");
}

DivisionByZeroError.prototype = new Error();
DivisionByZeroError.prototype.constructor = DivisionByZeroError;
```

However, I can not understand why the function constructor has to assign to itself again. That is,

```
DivisionByZeroError.prototype.constructor = DivisionByZeroError;
```

I think this is because `DivisionByZeroError.prototype` assigned to `new Error()` so the prototype was changed.

But I am not sure why even after commenting out that line. The code still works fine.

Demo code is put on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjchender/kksnfgvp/)

---

Reference:
[Exceptional Exception Handling in JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/exceptional-exception-handling-in-javascript/)
[A Guide to Proper Error Handling in JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/proper-error-handling-javascript/)

Comment: https://nodeway.wordpress.com/2015/02/16/javascript-prototype/ this might be useful to understand

Comment: Avoid that code, [using `new` for inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here) is horrible. Subclassing builtins like `Error` works best with ES6 `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind this, is that if you run the following code:

```
console.log(new Error().constructor)
```

it outputs:

```
"ƒ Error() { [native code] }"
```

Now, by standard, if you create a class, then the following should be true:

```
console.log(new MyClassName().constructor === MyClassName)
```

for example, the following is true:

```
(new Error().constructor) === Error; // true
```

A use for this could be like so:

```
function isArray(maybeArray) {
  return maybeArray.constructor === Array;
}
isArray([]); // true
isArray(new Array(10)); // true
isArray(false); // false

// or say this function
function makeAnotherOfObjectWithoutParameters(object) {
    return new object.constructor();
}
(makeAnotherOfObjectWithoutParameters([])); // empty array
```

So now say you want to see if an object is a `DivisionByZeroError`. You have your function like so:

```
function DivisionByZeroError(message) {
  this.name = "DivisionByZeroError";
  this.message = (message || "");
}

DivisionByZeroError.prototype = new Error();
```

now, you should expect the following to be true:

```
console.log(new DivisionByZeroError('my message').constructor === DivisionByZeroError);
```

but you would be surprised that it is false, so now you have to explicitly set the constructor like so:

```
DivisionByZeroError.prototype.constructor = DivisionByZeroError
```

and now the above code will work!

Hope this helped someone... I learnt something too!